# How to optimize storage of repeating values in mysql column?

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb

I have table in mysql with one column where values are the same for lots of rows (these are all 32 charactere strings). But those values are not a closed set of values known in advance. Is there a way to optimize storage for such scenario? Does mysql store it in some smart way?

I use MariaDB 10.

Comment: 'Does mysql store it in some smart way'- no it doesn't but who cares disk is cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

- If these strings are mostly different, don't do anything special.
- You could get a slight saving by compressing the strings and using a `TINYBLOB`.  But the hassle is not worth it.  (I have argued for such for much larger strings.
- If there is much repetition, you could 'normalize' them.  (Another table with id+string; then replace the string column with ids.)  A 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` would not overflow until 65K.

But...  Do the math.  How much might you save?  If it is less than 10%, one of my Rules of Thumb says "don't bother".

Keep in mind that most "solutions" are a tradeoff between speed and space.

You imply that they are all exactly 32?  If they are hex or ascii, then use

```
CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

Then use `ascii_general_ci` (eg, hex) for case folding or `ascii_bin` for no folding (eg, base64).

(Note:  If you give more details, I won't have to do as much 'hand-waving'.)